# Cloud SQL Proxy installation in Ubuntu (component not available)

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I installed the `gcloud CLI` as instructed: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb

In nutshell, I did the following commands:

```
1) sudo apt-get update

2) sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg curl sudo

3) echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

4) curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -

5) sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-cli

6) gcloud init (account previously configured)
```

And after all this I ran the command to install Cloud SQL Proxy:

```
gcloud components install cloud_sql_proxy
```

And in the console I get the following error: **ERROR: (gcloud.components.install)
The cloud_sql_proxy component(s) is unavailable through the packaging system
you are currently using. Please consider using a separate installation
of the Google Cloud CLI created through the default mechanism.**

Unfortunately I don't work too much on ubuntu and have no idea why I get this error and how I can fix it.

Here is the system version: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: The documentation shows how: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-auth-proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently, we don't ship the Cloud SQL Proxy as part of a Debian package.

Instead, we recommend downloading it directly from the storage bucket we publish releases to.

See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy#installation.